# SQL Statement Join Table is null query

Tags: sql, join

Hi i am using a Join table query to retrieve some data..

```
USE [AccountingSystem_TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spHRLeaveEntitlementBuildTemp]    Script Date: 03/14/2013 09:18:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spHRLeaveEntitlementBuildTemp]
    (   
     @CreatedUserID as nvarchar(9)
    ,@EmployeeID nvarchar(9) 
    ,@EmpName nvarchar(150)
    )
AS
BEGIN

    Select A.CodeHRLeaveType,
        COALESCE(B.LeaveBalance) LeaveBalance           
    From HRLeaveType A
        LEFT JOIN HRLeaveMaster B 
        On A.CodeHRLeaveType = B.CodeHRLeaveType
    Where   B.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID

    Delete dbo.HrLeaveMasterTemp
    Where UserID = @CreatedUserID 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[HrLeaveMasterTemp]
       ( [UserID]
        ,[EmployeeID] 
        ,[EmpName]
        ,[CodeHRLeaveType]
        ,[LeaveBalance]
        ,[Status] 
        )
    Select 
         @CreatedUserID             
        ,[EmployeeID]
        ,@EmpName
        ,[CodeHRLeaveType]
        ,[LeaveBalance]
        ,[Status]           
    From dbo.[HRLeaveMaster]
    Where EmployeeID =@EmployeeID
END
--Select * From HRLeaveMasterTemp
```

If leavebalance is null i need the table to show 0.. But the statement shows error.. Please Help Me..

Comment: Try the edited answer, whether it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

use `COALESCE`

```
Select  A.CodeHRLeaveType,
        COALESCE(B.LeaveBalance) LeaveBalance           
From    HRLeaveType A
        LEFT JOIN HRLeaveMaster B 
            On A.CodeHRLeaveType = B.CodeHRLeaveType
Where   B.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Comment: can't see any error in the code, what is the error message generated?

Comment: What is your database?..is it mysql ?

Comment: @user1617943 it's not mysql code you have posted. its the syntax used on sql server.

Comment: oops.. I am not even aware of that.. Am just a beginner.. :|

Answer (score 1):

in Oracle the replacement of null function is used with NVL Function.
in MySql the replacement of null function is used with IFNULL Function.

Please look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp. which may help you.

The statement should be -

```
Select A.CodeHRLeaveType,
    IFNULL(B.LeaveBalance,0) LeaveBalance           
From HRLeaveType A
    LEFT JOIN HRLeaveMaster B 
    On A.CodeHRLeaveType = B.CodeHRLeaveType
Where   B.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Comment: Its Shows 
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure spHRLeaveEntitlementBuildTemp, Line 12
'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: `Select
    A.CodeHRLeaveType
   ,B.LeaveBalance (LeaveBalance+ISNULL(LeaveBalance,0))      
 From HRLeaveType A
 Join HRLeaveMaster B On A.CodeHRLeaveType = B.CodeHRLeaveType
 Where B.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID`

Comment: it solves your problem. I have done the statement from the above link and after executing SELECT IFNULL( 1, 0 ) in my phpmyadmin.Anyway..thanks..